# can windows intune do a self service software distribution portal?

Tags: sccm, microsoft-intune

I want to give users a self-service software portal like sccm can do but sccm is huge and I have less than 100 users and many are mobile

From what I understand intune is for oob/mobile users. Does intune have a feature like sccm for self-service software distribution?

I cant find a good description of if/how intune can do this

EDIT: Maybe I be more direct with my issue/question
I have about 100 users and devices. We have on-prem AD and use Office 365 but they are not synced. We do not have Azure AD at all.

I want to have a self server software portal for users but not sure the best solution for my current setup. Intune? Azure app management (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-application-management)? SCCM (please dear lord no)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InTune accomplishes this via the company portal app for iOS/Android. If you are managing Windows 10 you can integrate Intune with Windows Store For Business.

Comment: Thanks for replying! so confusing with all the options. I update my question. Apparently there is also app management for Azure? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-application-management